# MySQL char vs. int

Tags: mysql, types

I'm currently having a discussion in my class about the datatypes `char` and `int` in MySQL.
We have a phone number of 8 individual numbers. However, we can't find any pros and cons for each of them.

Should we use the `char` type or the `int` type, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a fixed size then you can use `char(8)` -> 8B , mysql works much faster with fixed size fields, but if you chose `int` -> 4B you will save space and also if you will have a index on that field it will work faster then the char.

You can do a simple benchmark to test the speed of writes and reads using char(8) and int

There is **no** point in using variable length type like **varchar or varbinary** if you have a fixed size because performance will **decrease**

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want to represent the phone number, do you need area codes, country codes and stuff like that, and do you want to save it as a single column or do you want to split it up?

Personally, I would choose to represent area codes, country codes, and the phone number as 3 columns with the datatype `int`, as this would make it easier to find all phone numbers in one area, and so on. But if it's only purpose is to be a like a string value, the char would be sufficient, however i would consider using the `varchar` instead, if you have phone numbers for several countries.`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, we only need to store the 8 digits for each row. What will do the job better holding 8 numbers, char or int?

Comment: varchar would do the job, as you won't be able to store leading zeroes with an int value.

Comment: Both `char`, `varchar` and `int` would do the job. In Denmark phone numbers can't have a leading zero. I just need to know which one would be better to use, and why that is

Comment: All of them would be sufficient for the thing you want then, I would personally choose the `varchar`, as the data isn't really that big, and therefore would not influence performance that much. `varchar` would also be "ready for international phone numbers". But still, all of them can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the US exactly, but in Europe the national access code is a leading 0 , and international access code is a leading 00 or +. So that's a con to using INT, as the leading 0's would be lost. Further more you also have phone numbers that contain names and even though these names can be converted to numbers, it would probably be nice to keep them as a name. That's a second con to using INT. Last con is you can also have extension numbers, etc. All goes into favor of VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

I started using `VARCHAR` for storing phone numbers because it gives you more range in formats of different countries.  Storage is cheap.