# Best way to store status flag value in the table (char or int)

Tags: mysql, charts, integer

i need to have a column called **status** in the table. this status column can contain -> **activated** , **expired**, **deactivated**. so i am wondering why cant i create an integer type column called status and store them as 0, 1, 2 (expired, activated, deactivated). but we are asked to do these kind of things using. CHAR instead of Int. so it will be, **status Char(2)** and to store as 0, 1, 2.

why should i use Char as the column type instead of Integer is my question?

Comment: It depends on the options and the values you are going to store...

int => 0, 1, 2
char => yes, no, attended
==========
using char is more descriptive, IMHO it is the best practice

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896055/mysql-char-vs-int

Comment: @user2864740 so you mean, in this case its good to go with CHAR(2) than Integer? i am having only "activated , expired, deactivated" as values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a *flag* field I will usually use CHAR(1) so that I have somewhat *meaningful but internal* values such as `'A'`, `'E'`, `'D'` - I do *not* use sequential integers values in such a case as they reveal nothing about the information!

These flag values - even though thy are "more readable" are still mapped via constants such that no "magic values" appear in code. (Unfortunately they must still appear in Views and whatnot.)

Take care when combining flags, however: if a flag tries to represent too much (e.g. more than a *small discreet set of values*) then it probably is too complicated and needs to be split in multiple columns/relationships.

Comment: What if a new status comes later down the line, starting from letter A or E or D. where can we store or as what characters can we store ? isnt it better to have integers as  0, 1, 2 for status column?

Comment: @mazraara In both cases these values should represent a *small discreet set of values* - as long as they are distinct it makes no difference, I find choosing *meaningful* values can keep things more tidy (but use constants in both cases!). If I run out of logical letters then I've already have a column that should not be a *flag* column! Also, it may be the case that a longer name is required for readability/maintainable - if so, then use that! *Do not prioritize "performance".* Also remember that flag columns are not orthogonal to FKs or other modeling constraints.

Comment: And if you're *only* going to store integers value, then by all means, use a bloody integer type. Do this because it makes sense given how you prefer to encode the flag (perhaps from existing data), but not for "performance" reasons.

Answer (score 2):

My preference is that we have a StatusType table that has values in increments of 10 (10, 20, 30 ...). This table has a description field as well as an IsActive column.

This allows us to easily set status on rows. We also use the description in our enums in code to make it more readable.

I do not see any benefit to using letters versus numbers as a single letter is still not descriptive and SQL SERVER is a giant calculator that loves numbers. Again just my opinion. It matters more how you intend to consume the data.