# MySQL: Performance difference between char(4) faster then smallint(5, unisgned)

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-performance

I am running a MySQL 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log  Server where I have the option of saving in char(4) or in smallint(5, unsigned). 
There will be a primary index on the column and the key will be used as a referrence accross tables.

What is faster? Char or Int?

Comment: It's hard to understand how you have this choice. If it's numeric, save it as binary. If it's character data, save it as `CHAR`. It can't be both at the same time.

Comment: You want better performance? Upgrade! Version 5.5 is almost a decade old, and many tens of programmer years since then have been spent making MySQL faster.

Comment: @user207421 In fact I am importing data where I do have the choice how to save it within my database. Both options are within the to be imported dataset.

Comment: @O.Jones Valid point! I looked it up and atctually I am running 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log (sorry my mistake). Never the less, still valid feedback. I fear that I will run into a ton of problems adapting my application incl. infrastructure e.g. solr. It might not be worth the faster performance and better to wait until an upgrade to ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: 'Both options are within the to be imported dataset' how? What is the name and purpose of the column? Columns don't have both fixed-width display and fixed-prevision numeric semantics at the same time. These are opposed to each other. The implications are large and you'd better get this right straight away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsigned `SMALLINT` values use two bytes and have values in the range [0, 65535]. `CHAR(4)` values take four bytes.  So, indexing `SMALLINT` values will make for a smaller index. Smaller is faster. Plus indexes on character columns usually have all sorts of character-set and case-insensitivity monkey business built in to them, which also takes time and space.

But, for a table with at most 65K rows, the effect of this choice will be so small you'll have trouble measuring it.  If you build something that's hard to debug, you'll spend your precious time and ten thousand times as much computer time debugging it  than it will save.

Design your tables so they match your application. If you're using a four-digit number use `SMALLINT`.

The next person to work on your code (even if that person is you a year from now) will thank you for a clear implementation.

And keep in mind that MySQL ignores the number in parentheses on INT declarations.   `SMALLINT(4)`, `SMALLINT(5)`, and `SMALLINT` all mean precisely the same thing. MySQL uses the native processor integer datatypes: `TINYINT` is an 8-bit number, `SMALLINT` a 16-bit number, `INT` a 32-bit number, and `BIGINT` a 64-bit number. Likewise `FLOAT` is a 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point number and `DOUBLE` a 64-bit one. The number of digits `SMALLINT(4)` is a nod to SQL standards compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed informaation. I go with the number version. One last question, you mentioned that (4) and (5) are the same. What is the reasoning behind it then?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by O. Jones, SMALLINT will be faster and more space-efficient.

This is related to the following answer: [mysql-char-vs-int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896055/mysql-char-vs-int)

Also, MySQL Documentation:
[CHAR and VARCHAR types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html)
[Integer Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:  The difference between `CHAR(4)` and `SMALLINT` is insignificant.  It should not influence you choice of datatypes.  Instead, use the datatypes that match the data.

Case 2:  If you are comparing `TINYINT` to `VARCHAR(255)`, the answer is probably different.  Note that there is a much bigger difference in the choices.

Case 3:  If the choice comes down to whether to "normalize" a column, there are arguments either way.  I much prefer using a `CHAR(2)` for `country_code` than normalizing in order to shrink to a `TINYINT`.  The overhead of extra normalization always(?) outweighs the space savings.

Another consideration:  How many secondary keys are on the table?  And how many other tables will you be joining to?

Case 4:  `PRIMARY KEY(big_string)` but no secondary keys.  There is no possibly no advantage in switching to an int.

Case 5:  Since secondary keys include the PK, consider:

```
PRIMARY KEY(big_string),
INDEX(foo),
INDEX(bar)
```

versus

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),   -- surrogate AUTO_INCREMENT
INDEX(big_string),
INDEX(foo),
INDEX(bar)
```

The latter will take less disk space.

Another consideration:  Fetching a row is far more costly than comparing an int or string.  My point is that you should not worry about comparison performance; you should look at the bigger picture when optimizing.

Case 6:  USA 5-digit zip code.  `CHAR(5)` (5 bytes) is reasonable.  `MEDIUMINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` (3 bytes) is better because it does everything better.  (And it is a very rare case of the `*INT(n)` being meaningful.)

And the debate goes on and on.